Построение сферы с 96 точками/фигурами
Пытаюсь построить геосферу с 96 пятиугольниками. ChatGPT пишет, что для построения геосферы из 96 пятиугольников надо 150 шестиугольников. Однако каждый раз генерируемый им код, не дает нормальной сферы. Помогите пожалуйста построить сферу.
Уточнение. Мне нужно чтобы на сфере были равномерно расположены 96 точек (фигур, пяти/шестиугольники) с заполнением между ними. Заполнение может быть любым, главное чтобы его было больше по площади чем этих самых фигур. Чем больше площадь заполнения по отношению к площади 96 точек, тем лучше.

А какой симметрией обладает эта геосфера? Икосаэдрическая (Goldberg polyhedra) подразумевает 12 пятиугольников

Уточните задачу пожалуйста и уберите домыслы ChatGPT. Вам надо построить геосферу с 96 пятиугольниками и N шестиугольниками? Или шестиугольники  могут отсутствовать или быть другими полигонами? Вносите уточнения в тело вопроса - кнопка "править".

Заметим, что для существования такого замкнутого многогранника, построенного из n вершин, образующих только пяти- и шестиугольные грани, согласно теореме Эйлера для многогранников, утверждающей справедливость равенства
|
n
|
−
|
e
|
+
|
f
|
2
{\displaystyle |n|-|e|+|f|=2} (где
|
n
|
,
|
e
|
{\displaystyle |n|,|e|} и
|
f
|
{\displaystyle |f|} соответственно количество вершин, ребер и граней), необходимым условием является наличие ровно 12 пятиугольных граней и
n
/
2
−
10
{\displaystyle n/2-10} шестиугольных граней.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD

Вот это не ответ, но интересно https://book.etudes.ru/articles/football/

мне в целом надо как-то замостить сферу так, чтобы она состояла из некоторых полигонов, чтобы всё это было симметрично, и присутствовало 96 неких точек (фигур, например пяти/шестиугольников) равномерно распределенных по поверхности сферы и с заполнением между ними (то есть сфера не может состоять только из 96 фигур). А уж каким образом это сделать я и пытаюсь узнать. Так что другие полигоны тоже допустимы. Главное количество точек (фигур) равное 96

Соответственно отредактируйте вопрос и название пожалуйста )

@Elijah_Pris, для меня "замостить" и "с заполнением между ними" - это прямо противоположные понятия. Так что вообще нифига не понятно.

Берём куб. Каждую его грань разрезаем на 16 квадратов. Все получившиеся точки отодвигаем от центра куба на одно и тоже расстояние. Получается 96-тигранник, все грани - четырёхугольники.
Я пока не доказал что все эти четырёхугольники будут плоскими. Но грани куба можно разбить на четыре квадрата. Каждый квадрат разбивается на четыре треугольника с вершной в центре квадрата. Тогда мы получим сферу из 96 треугольников.

В общем-то да, при текущей постановке задачи это решение.

Про плоскость в вопросе не сказано

@Kromster, хороший геоид должен быть из плоских граней.
